# Use AWS Beanstalk Hooks to do an HTTP GET request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to do an HTTP GET call during AWS Beanstalk deployment and make it roll back to previous version in case of an error response, even though the application has been successfully deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ELB health check to customise which of your application endpoints is checked for application health, see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html).

There are slightly different settings depending on which kind of load balancer you're using, eg [classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-clb.html#using-features.managing.elb.healthchecks) or [application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html#environments-cfg-alb-console-process-healthchecks).